# WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'spek2' failed to discover tests with Gradle v5.2.1

Tags: junit, gradle-kotlin-dsl, spek

Having a bit of an issue with using Spek 2 with the Gradle Kotlin DSL. When I right click on my tests folder and hit `run all tests` I get this error: `WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'spek2' failed to discover tests`. Am I doing the build script incorrectly? This is within a subproject.

```kotlin
//subproject build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
    java
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation(kotlin("reflect", Vof.kotlin))
    testImplementation(kotlin("test", Vof.kotlin))
    testImplementation(group = "org.spekframework.spek2", name = "spek-dsl-jvm", version = Vof.spek) {
        exclude(group = "org.jetbrains.kotlin")
    }
    testRuntimeOnly(group = "org.spekframework.spek2", name = "spek-runner-junit5", version = Vof.spek) {
        exclude(group = "org.jetbrains.kotlin")
        exclude(group = "org.junit.platform")
    }
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:${Vof.junitPlatform}")
    testImplementation(gradleTestKit())
}

tasks {
    named<Test>("test") {
        useJUnitPlatform {
            includeEngines("spek2")
        }
    }
}
```

I tried it using the format from the tutorial as well:

```kotlin
tasks {
    test {
        useJUnitPlatform {
            includeEngines("spek2")
        }
    }
}
```

but it has the same error. Spek is not able to find the tests for some reason. Any ideas?

**edit:** here is the full stacktrace

```
Feb 24, 2019 9:41:07 PM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher handleThrowable
WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'spek2' failed to discover tests
java.lang.IllegalStateException: clz.java.`package` must not be null
    at org.spekframework.spek2.runtime.scope.PathBuilder$Companion.from(Path.kt:86)
    at org.spekframework.spek2.runtime.SpekRuntime.discover(SpekJvmRuntime.kt:30)
    at org.spekframework.spek2.junit.SpekTestEngine.discover(SpekTestEngine.kt:76)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverEngineRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:177)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:164)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discover(DefaultLauncher.java:120)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:52)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

## **UPDATE: this was identified as a bug and was fixed in Spek 2.0.1.**